# How to create FIRUser with sign in with custom token?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using it for iOS in Swift programming language!

- I am using Firebase for my Backend stuff
- I am using Facebook account kit for log in.

  - I am getting Account kit access token

So I basically use Account kit access token

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithCustomToken(accessToken.tokenString, completion: { (user, error) in
        print(user)
        print("\n\n\n\(error)")
    })
```

I get error in console that

**"Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17000 "The custom token format is incorrect. Please check the documentation." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The custom token format is incorrect. Please check the documentation., error_name=ERROR_INVALID_CUSTOM_TOKEN})"**

Reference to the Firebase [click here!](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/custom-auth#authenticate-with-firebase)

Comment: Hi, did you find a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credentialWithAccessToken(accessToken.tokenString)
```

followed by signInWithCredential with the credential.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/facebook-login#authenticate_with_firebase

Comment: Nope that doesn't work. Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17999 "An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7fcdf4240080 {Error Domain=FIRAuthInternalErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={FIRAuthErrorUserInfoDeserializedResponseKey=<CFBasicHash 0x7fcdf422e4c0 [0x102b26a40]>{type = immutable dict, count = 3,
entries =>
 0 : <CFString 0x7fcdf4230960 [0x102b26a40]>{contents = "message"} = <CFString 0x7fcdf422e440 [0x102b26a40]>{contents = "invalid access_token, error code 43."}
I get this type of error!!!